# Iterate through a list of 3 mil. JSON objects | Performance

Tags: python, arrays, json, performance

I have 2 arrays.

Array `users` contains some user data and has 3.5 mil. records.

Array `transactions` contains some transactions data and has 140k records.

Now I want to loop through each user and look up which types of transactions he did and save this information in a new array, lets call it Array C, so Array C will also have 3.5 mil. records.

Later I want to use Array C to create a point cloud.

I am doing it really simple right now:

```
with open('final/users.json', 'r') as f:
  users = json.load(f)

with open('final/transactions.json', 'r') as f:
  transactions = json.load(f)

result = []
count = 0

for user in users:
  data_elem = {'user': user, 'memberships': 0, 'credits': 0}
  print('working on: ' + str(user['id']) + ' count: ' + str(count))
  for transaction in transactions:
    if user['id'] == transaction['user_id']:
      if transaction['type'] == 'membership':
        data_elem['memberships'] += 1
      elif transaction['type'] == 'credits':
        data_elem['credits'] += 1
      else:
        print('unknow type: ' + transaction['type'])
        break
  result.append(data_elem)
  count += 1
  # Just for testing
  if count == 2000:
    break

with open('final/analysed/membership_credits_buys.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(result, f)
```

With this approach the script will be active for 2 hours~ + the time I will need to loop again and create the point cloud. (Maybe its better to create the point cloud already in the first loop).

I am just curious whether there is a faster approach. I have found `numpy` and I am currently looking how it can help, but maybe someone here knows a better library or approach.

Comment: If you want this to be fast you'll use an indexed datastore rather than files on disk.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? It would be very helpful. If not, profiling data are the minimum information needed to help you. Besides, I expect Python objects and hashing to be the bottleneck here. There is not much to to apart from not using Python (preventing nearly all possible optimizations here). SimdJson could help. A manual parsing (less robust) can help even more (though Python will be the bottleneck again).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I got the data from a DB, using the DB is also very very slow. I thought that loading everything into memory will be faster via python. It just seems there is no fast approach.

Comment: [Profile](https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler/) your script and see where it's spending most of it's time.

Comment: @Roman, how you use your database matters; you want to be indexing on the items to retrieve. If you don't actually build and use indices relevant to your search criteria, you get no performance benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file I/O part and JSON parsing cannot be optimised further unless you would move away from JSON and store your data in a relational database. But assuming this is how it has to be, we can focus on the processing part:

Instead of iterating the complete list of transactions for each user, it will be better to first create a dictionary from the users list first, keyed by user id, and then to populate that dictionary with the corresponding transactions. This way you only need to loop over the transactions once.

A minor thing: keep the name of the keys the same. So don't translate "membership" to "memberships"... this is just overhead that is not worth it.

```
result = {
    user['id']: {'user': user, 'membership': 0, 'credits': 0}
    for user in users
}
for transaction in transactions:
      data_elem = result[transaction['user_id']]
      try:
          data_elem[transaction['type']] += 1
      except:
          print('unknown type: ' + transaction['type'])
          break
# convert dict to list
result = list(result.values())
```

#### Database design

In case you have the option to use an SQL database, then the schema should be designed somewhat like this:

`Users` table:

- Primary key: `user_id`
- Other columns, like maybe `name`, `address`, `dob`, ...etc

`Transactions` table:

- Primary key: `transaction_id`
- Foreign key: `user_id` (having non-unique index)
- `type`
- Other columns, like maybe `amount`, `transaction_date`, ...etc

Then the SQL to retrieve the result would be:

```sql
select    u.user_id,
          min(u.name) name,
          min(u.address) address,
          -- ...etc...
          count(case t.type when 'membership' then 1 end) memberships,
          count(case t.type when 'credits' then 1 end) credits
from      Users u
left join Transactions t
       on u.user_id = t.user_id
group by  u.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats actually a very good idea! Also the data was initially in a DB, but also very very slow. I thought pulling the data from the DB and into JSON would be faster. Seems I was wrong. I should maybe go back to the DB approach and figure out why its slow there

Comment: If the db is a relational database, with a normalised schema, and with the appropriate *index* on the foreign key in the `transactions` table, it should be *lightening* fast. But modern day designers often store data in a database in a non-normalised way (sometimes even packing things together in a JSON string). This can be a disaster for performance. I am old school, and in my book a DB design **has** to be normalised, or it's bad.